# How to `ls` only one level deep?

Tags: bash, ls

I have lots subdirectories containing data, and I want a short list of which jobs (subdirectories) I have. I'm not happy with the following command.

```
$ ls H2*
H2a:
energy.dat overlap.dat 
norm.dat zdip.dat ...
(much more)
H2b:
energy.dat overlap.dat
norm.dat zdip.dat ... 
(much more)
```

This needless clutter defeats the purpose of the wildcard (limiting the output). How can I limit the output to one level deep? I'd like to see the following output

```
H2a/ H2b/ H2z/
```

Thanks for your help,
Nick

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this

```
ls -d H2*/
```

The `-d` option is supposed to list "directories only", but by itself just lists

```
.
```

which I personally find kind of strange.  The wildcard is needed to get an actual list of directories.

**UPDATE**: As @Philipp points out, you can do this even more concisely and without leaving bash by saying

```
echo H2*/
```

The difference is that `ls` will print the items on separate lines, which is often useful for piping to other functions.

Comment: If mydir is the name of a directory and you execute 'ls mydir', ls shows the contents of mydir. If you execute 'ls -d mydir', then ls shows lists mydir without showing its contents.  Now if no directory or wildcard is provided, then ls operates on '.' (i.e. the current directory) by default. So 'ls -d' is equivalent to 'ls -d .', which should list '.' without showing it's contents. I hope that clarifies a bit why a directory name or wildcard is required.

Comment: The -d option is superior to the echo solution when you want to combine with e.g. -l for a long listing, to see folder permissions. Thanks very much!

Comment: piping output - resp. file lists - of `ls` to other functions is usually a bad idea; better use `find`.

Answer (score 22):

You should consider using find, like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "H2*"
```

*NOTE: Putting "-type d" before "-maxdepth 1" results in a warning on Debian Linux ("find: warning: you have specified the global option -maxdepth after the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e., -maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments.") No such warning is issued on Mac.*

Comment: consider putting -maxdepth before -type, your command probably will run into a warning. Nevermind, not a big deal.

Comment: @MichaelMao, following your suggestion, I proposed an edit in which "-maxdepth 1" occurs before "-type d".

Answer (score 12):

```
echo H2*
```

It's Bash who does the expansion, so you don't even need `ls`.

Should you have both files and directories starting with `H2`, you can append a slash to restrict the glob to directories:

```
echo H2*/
```

Comment: Interesting point.  But this will include files starting with "H2", and the OP wants only subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

Use `tree` by Steve Baker at http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/
It fills in for a lot of things that are missing from `ls`.
To list directories one layer deep:

```
tree -adi -L 1 H2*
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
ls | grep H2*
```

Comment: Perfect for me. Also allows you to do things like `ls -l | grep pattern`.

Comment: When you have a lot of files in the dir, it results in huge time and resources waste.